# Fastest way to do _simple_ templating with Python

Tags: python, performance, templating

After using cheetah and mako at their functional minimum (only for substitution) for sometime, I started asking myself whether just using string.Template wouldn't be the better and simpler approach for my use case(less deps). 
In addition I wondered whether it would be reasonable to import these templates as .py files to avoid .open() on each call. This would make handling templates a little more complicated but other than that I'd save a lot of system calls.

What do you guys think? 
*I'm well aware that my present templating is speedy enough for 99.9% of the use cases I will go through.*

Thank you for any Input

Comment: If it's fast enough in the 99.9% of the cases then why bother? Refactoring would take much more time then the time you'd save.

Comment: As written above, I just want to explore this topic further and have no intension to improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trying and reading I found string.Template from the Core Library to be the fastest - I just wrapped in my own simple class to encapsulate the file-access/reads et voilà.